# Can someone please help me what is wrong with this code

Tags: r

> library(readr)
> bookings_df <- read_csv("hotel_bookings.csv")
> Error: 'hotel_bookings.csv' does not exist in current working directory ('C:/Users/fionn/OneDrive/Documents').

Comment: try to set working directory

Comment: As the message suggests, there is no file `hotel_bookings.csv` found in your working directory. If the file is located in a different folder than 'C:/Users/fionn/OneDrive/Documents', you can change your working directory to the target folder with `setwd("your/wd")`.

Comment: Yes. got it . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other users said, this error message informs that your file `hotel_bookings.csv` is not located in 'C:/Users/fionn/OneDrive/Documents' folder, which is your current working directory.

Some possible solutions to get `read_csv` to work:

1. Save `hotel_bookings.csv` in the folder 'C:/Users/fionn/OneDrive/Documents', and then rerun `read_csv("hotel_bookings.csv")`.
2. You can use `read_csv(file.choose())` to pick the `hotel_bookings.csv` file from its current location without having to save it to the current working directory.
3. You use the full path as the input to `read_csv`. For example if `hotel_bookings.csv` is located in 'C:/Users/fionn/myfolder', and you are using Windows : `read_csv("C:\\Users\\fionn\\myfolder\\hotel_bookings.csv")`
4. Change the working directory to the current location of `hotel_bookings.csv`. If you are using Windows:

```
setwd("C:\\Users\\fionn\\myfolder")
read_csv("hotel_bookings.csv")
```

Comment: Clear. It worked. Thanks

Comment: Nice if it helped. Please kindly accept my answer.